# Database definition with nested attributes and HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nested-attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to track GPS satellites as they cross the sky.  I receive 'SKY' messages every 5 seconds, containing location and signal strength data for each satellite currently visible. The database contains tables for 'skies', 'sats', 'tracks' and 'points'. The idea is that each sky received will add a location point to each of its satellite's track. Schema is...

```
  create_table "points", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "track_id"
    t.integer "az"
    t.integer "el"
    t.integer "ss"
    t.boolean "used"
    t.boolean "duplicate"
    t.integer "PRN"
    t.bigint "sky_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["PRN"], name: "index_points_on_PRN"
    t.index ["created_at"], name: "index_points_on_created_at"
    t.index ["sky_id"], name: "index_points_on_sky_id"
    t.index ["track_id"], name: "index_points_on_track_id"
  end

  create_table "sats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "PRN"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6
    t.index ["PRN"], name: "index_sats_on_PRN"
  end

  create_table "sats_skies", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "sky_id", null: false
    t.bigint "sat_id", null: false
    t.index ["sat_id", "sky_id"], name: "index_sats_skies_on_sat_id_and_sky_id"
    t.index ["sky_id", "sat_id"], name: "index_sats_skies_on_sky_id_and_sat_id"
  end

  create_table "skies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "klass"
    t.string "tag"
    t.string "device"
    t.float "time"
    t.float "xdop"
    t.float "ydop"
    t.float "vdop"
    t.float "tdop"
    t.float "hdop"
    t.float "pdop"
    t.float "gdop"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["created_at"], name: "index_skies_on_created_at"
  end

  create_table "tracks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "sat_id"
    t.index ["sat_id"], name: "index_tracks_on_sat_id"
  end
```

The model definitions are...

```
class Sky < ApplicationRecord
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  has_and_belongs_to_many :sats, inverse_of: :sky, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :points, inverse_of: :sky

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sats, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :points, allow_destroy: true

end
```

```
class Sat < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skies, inverse_of: :sat, autosave: true
  has_one :track, inverse_of: :sat

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skies, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :track, allow_destroy: true
end
```

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :points, inverse_of: :track
  belongs_to :sat, inverse_of: :track

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :points, allow_destroy: true

end
```

```
class Point < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sky, inverse_of: :point     #, optional: true
  belongs_to :track, inverse_of: :point   #, optional: true

end
```

When a sky message is received, it checks the previous sky message to see which of it's satellites also existed there. For those found, the point is just added to that satellite's track table. If the satellite was not visible in the last sky, a new sat record is created, and its location 'point' is added to the new sat's track.

Note that the point record has foreign keys for both the track, and the sky records.

Initially, I had all this working, but I was creating the sky record, then creating the sat/track records (if needed), then saving the point. A power failure while processing a sky message caused the database to contain a sat/track with no points. I realize I could just surround all this processing with a transaction block, but thought a cleaner solution would be to create all the various components for a sky message in memory and when complete save the whole batch with a single new_sky.save.

But try as I may, I don't seem to be able to get the proper combination 'reverse_of', 'nested_attributes' and other definition attributes to successfully save the results. With everything configured as listed here, I am currently getting the following while processing the first satellite in the first sky message received...

```
D, [2020-05-03 10:37:32.410281000 -0500 CDT#83744] DEBUG -- GpsComms: ************* This sat (#8) not found in previous SKY, create new *************
E, [2020-05-03 10:37:32.436055000 -0500 CDT#83744] ERROR -- GpsComms: Sat Processing Failed
E, [2020-05-03 10:37:32.436454000 -0500 CDT#83744] ERROR -- GpsComms: {:Rescue=>"#<ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for track (:point in Track)>"}
E, [2020-05-03 10:37:32.436786000 -0500 CDT#83744] ERROR -- GpsComms: Could not find the inverse association for track (:point in Track) - (ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError)
```

With other combinations of options (reverse_of:, optional:, etc) I get error messages stating various object must exist.

I think I'm close. I'm hoping somebody can figure out the correct combination of definitions to get this to work.

Thanks for any help,

UPDATE:
I believed that the error above ("Could not find the inverse association for track (:point in Track)") was being generated when attempting to save the new sky object. It is actually being generated when the new point is being added to the points collection.

At this point I have created the new sky with

> sky=Sky.new( parameters)

The satellite has been created with

> sat=sky.sats.build(parameters)

The track with

> track=sat.build_track(*empty*)

Now I can do either

> new_point=sat.track.points.build(parameters)

or

> sat.track.points << Point.new(parameters)

to generate the inverse assoc error.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:
Thanks to the suggestion from Eyselandic below -- here is a run-able file. It errors out on the last line with the 'inverse association' error.

```
# Activate the gem you are reporting the issue against.
gem 'activerecord', '6.0.0'
require 'active_record'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'logger'

# Ensure backward compatibility with Minitest 4
Minitest::Test = MiniTest::Unit::TestCase unless defined?(Minitest::Test)

# This connection will do for database-independent bug reports.
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'postgresql', 
  database: 'database_name',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
)
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end


ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table "points", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "track_id"
    t.integer "az"
    t.integer "el"
    t.integer "ss"
    t.boolean "used"
    t.boolean "duplicate"
    t.integer "PRN"
    t.bigint "sky_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["PRN"], name: "index_points_on_PRN"
    t.index ["created_at"], name: "index_points_on_created_at"
    t.index ["sky_id"], name: "index_points_on_sky_id"
    t.index ["track_id"], name: "index_points_on_track_id"
  end

  create_table "sats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "PRN"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6
    t.index ["PRN"], name: "index_sats_on_PRN"
  end

  create_table "sats_skies", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "sky_id", null: false
    t.bigint "sat_id", null: false
    t.index ["sat_id", "sky_id"], name: "index_sats_skies_on_sat_id_and_sky_id"
    t.index ["sky_id", "sat_id"], name: "index_sats_skies_on_sky_id_and_sat_id"
  end

  create_table "skies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "klass"
    t.string "tag"
    t.string "device"
    t.float "time"
    t.float "xdop"
    t.float "ydop"
    t.float "vdop"
    t.float "tdop"
    t.float "hdop"
    t.float "pdop"
    t.float "gdop"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["created_at"], name: "index_skies_on_created_at"
  end

  create_table "tracks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "sat_id"
    t.index ["sat_id"], name: "index_tracks_on_sat_id"
  end
end

class Sky < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sats, inverse_of: :sky, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :points, inverse_of: :sky

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sats, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :points, allow_destroy: true
end

class Sat < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skies, inverse_of: :sat, autosave: true
  has_one :track, inverse_of: :sat

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skies, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :track, allow_destroy: true
end

class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :points, inverse_of: :track
  belongs_to :sat, inverse_of: :track

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :points, allow_destroy: true

end

class Point < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sky, inverse_of: :point     #, optional: true
  belongs_to :track, inverse_of: :point   #, optional: true
end

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_association_stuff
    sky_attr= {
      :klass=>"SKY",
      :device=>"/dev/ttyAMA0",
      :xdop=>0.62,
      :ydop=>0.89,
      :vdop=>0.94,
      :tdop=>1.15,
      :hdop=>1.23,
      :gdop=>2.28,
      :pdop=>1.55
    }
    sky = Sky.new(sky_attr)

    sat = sky.sats.build(:PRN=>7)

    track = sat.build_track

    point_attr= {
      :PRN=>7,
      :el=>61,
      :az=>340,
      :ss=>21,
      :used=>true,
#      :sky_id=>nil,
      :duplicate=>false
    }
    point=sat.track.points.build( point_attr)  

    sky.save

  end
end
```

Error:

```
Error:
BugTest#test_association_stuff:
ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for track (:point in Track)
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:240:in `check_validity_of_inverse!'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:474:in `check_validity!'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:43:in `initialize'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:237:in `new'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:237:in `association'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:286:in `inverse_association_for'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:107:in `set_inverse_instance'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:187:in `initialize_attributes'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:318:in `block in build_record'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:328:in `initialize'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:70:in `new'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:70:in `new'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:158:in `build_association'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:317:in `build_record'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:108:in `build'
    /Users/sjf/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:316:in `build'
    active_record_gem.rb:136:in `test_association_stuff'
```

Comment: You can create a runnable single file with the bug tracking template, maybe easier for others to help you then https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/bug_report_templates/active_record_gem.rb